# VBA sub not executing unless in debug mode

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing some automation in Excel with VBA. We have several versions of a template and I'm working on functionality that allows users to import data from older versions into the newest version of the template.

Here's some of that code:

```
If .Range("E63").Interior.Color <> .Range("M5").Interior.Color Then
    Call switch
    .Range("E63:E142").Value = PTWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration").Range("E63:E142").Value
    Call switch
...
```

The `switch` sub swaps two the columns in the new template to properly line them up so we can import from the old template more easily. The issue is that that sub doesn't run unless I step through the sub in debug mode. The values get imported into the template, but the columns don't switch like they're supposed to.

```
Sub switch()

    Dim inputValue As Variant
    Dim calculatedValue As Variant

    If Range("F63").Interior.Color = Range("M5").Interior.Color Then
        inputValue = "F"
        calculatedValue = "E"
    Else
        inputValue = "E"
        calculatedValue = "F"
    End If
    
    
    Range(calculatedValue & "63:" & calculatedValue & "142").Formula = Range(calculatedValue & "63:" & calculatedValue & "142").Value
    Range(inputValue & "63").Formula = "=" & calculatedValue & "63"
    
    If inputValue = "F" Then
        Range(inputValue & "64:" & inputValue & "98").Formula = "=" & calculatedValue & "64-" & calculatedValue & "63"
        
    Else
        Range(inputValue & "64:" & inputValue & "98").Formula = "=" & calculatedValue & "64+" & inputValue & "63"
        
    End If
    
    Range(inputValue & "63:" & inputValue & "142").Interior.Color = Range("M13").Interior.Color
    Range(calculatedValue & "63:" & calculatedValue & "142").Interior.Color = Range("M5").Interior.Color

End Sub
```

I did some research and a lot of people recommend putting `DoEvents` after the call to 'slow things down' and effectively wait for the sub to finish. But that hasn't worked.

I also have almost identical code elsewhere that does the exact same thing, but from a different version, and it works with the `DoEvents` call.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Edit:
Added `switch` sub.

Comment: It may help to also include the code for your `Switch` function.

Comment: @brax added the switch function.

Comment: Your `Switch` function has unqualified ranges, so those are going to always assume the `ActiveSheet` - that can produce different results when debugging and using multiple sheets. Qualify those ranges as well so the code does not have to make assumptions.

Comment: I updated the ranges to this: 'ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range...'. That doesn't seem to have made a difference unfortunately (assuming I did it correctly).

Comment: Is that the same sheet you qualified the ranges in the top snippet of code? You do not show that part, but I'm assuming you want those to match.

Comment: Dang, that worked, thank you so much. The macro opens up the old template at some point to import the values, so I guess at some point, that becomes the active sheet instead of the template we're importing to (the newest one). Thank you again.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could add an argument to the `Switch` function that passes the worksheet you want to use and then qualify those ranges using that variable. It might clean up the code a bit.